# Fix div after scroll makes scrollbar jitter

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to make a simple jQuery function that makes a navbar div fixed whenever the window is scrolled down past a certain point.
I have set this point as the height of my header div, since it's whenever you scroll past this div that the navbar should become fixed.
It's working fine, except if I click and drag the window scrollbar and position it right about where the div should become fixed, it jitters up and down. What could be causing this?

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
        <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='header'></div>
        <div class='navbar'></div>
        <div class='about'></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS code:
    body
    {
        margin: 0;
    }

```
.header
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

.about
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.header').height() && $('.navbar').css('position') != 'fixed')
    {
        $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'blue');
        $('.navbar').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0'
        });
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('.header').height() && $('.navbar').css('position') != 'relative')
    {
        $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'pink');
        $('.navbar').css({
            'position': 'relative'
        })
    }
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30){
         $('nav').addClass('sticky');
     }
     else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 30){
         $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
     }
 });
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body{
  min-height: 800px;
}
.wrapper{
   min-height: 50px;
   margin-top:30px;
   
 }
 nav{
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        color: #000;
        padding: 15px;
        transition: all .3s;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
nav ul li{
        display:inline;
      }
      nav ul li a{
        padding: 8px;
      }
    .sticky{
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left:0;
        position:fixed;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

here is the working demo for you in snippet

Comment: Thanks for the code. I've compared my own code with this one, and I can't figure out where my own code goes wrong. Do you have an idea?

Comment: let me check dear